# What do the labels mean in this latin pos tagging?

Tags: computational-linguistics, latin, pos-tagging

I'm using `cltk`, a Python library for processing of classical languages.

I'm pos-tagging an example sentence, but I don't understand the output.

```
tagger.tag_unigram('Gallia est omnis divisa in partes tres')
# >>> [('Gallia', 'N-S---FB-'), ('est', 'V3SPIA---'), ('omnis', 'A-P---MA-'), ('divisa', 'T-SRPPFN-'), ('in', 'R--------'), ('partes', 'N-P---FA-'), ('tres', 'M--------')]
```

What does, for example `'N-S---FB-'` mean?

[From the docs of cltk](http://docs.cltk.org/en/latest/latin.html#pos-tagging).

Comment: _Est_ is `Verb 3rd.person Singular Feminine B`, and I have no idea what `B` means; given the fact that _est_ is an auxiliary verb and highly irregular, `B` may be some reference to grammatical phenomena. Btw, if you want a different parse of that sentence, [try this](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/BelloGallico.pdf).

Comment: @jlawler  **'B'** surprisingly (in position 8) means Ablative.  The full **Key** link in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CLTK** is producing parsing programs for classical Languages. Information on the LATIN version, including the copyright notice, can be found at [kyle-p-johnson (notebooks)](http://kyle-p-johnson.com/notebooks/):

Information is posted in a nine-letter string.
Each position in the sequence signifies a category.

> Nine string sequence:
>   .1. part of speech .2.person .3.number .4.tense  .5.mood .6.voice
>   .7.gender .8.case .9.degree.

2.3.4.5.6 follow the traditional sequence for parsing a verb. The verb **est** is therefore described as **v3spia** ="verb.- 3rd person.-singular.-  present.-indicative. -active."

Many of  the codes will not be difficult to learn:
**person** 1/2/3 **;**  **number** s/p (singular/plural) **;** **voice** a/p (active/passive) **gender** m/f/n  **degree** c/s (comparative/superlative)

1.4.5.8 have larger sets,  (e.g. B means 'ablative' vid.sup.)
The **m** in .1. for **tres**  indicates a numeral, but. **m** in .5. would indicate imperative. [Full key.](https://github.com/cltk/latin_treebank_perseus)